# Синтаксис аргумента `--` программы grep

Tags: linux, bash, debian, grep

```
$ nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -- '--with-debug'
```

Не совсем понятно что означает такой синтаксис команды `grep`. А именно первые два тире `--`. Может опечатка?

---

Кажется врубился, это хак чтобы защитить шаблон начинающийся на `-`. Вот нормальная человеческая версия:

```
$ nginx -V 2>&1 | grep -e '--with-debug'
```

Comment: Стандартно (для утилит, которые используют  `getopt_long()` для разбора аргументов) `--` означает конец *optional arguments*, т.е. далее идут "обычные" (не ключи) аргументы командной строки вне зависимости от того, какой у них первый символ

Comment: @avp, Они называются *позиционными*.

Comment: @0andriy, может кто-то так их и называет, но в описании  [Program Argument Syntax Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argument-Syntax.html#Argument-Syntax) нет ничего похожего на такую классификацию, как *позиционные* (или *ключевые*) аргументы. Заодно, по сути вопроса, вот как там описывают '--' -  *`"The argument ‘--’ terminates all options; any following arguments are treated as non-option arguments, even if they begin with a hyphen"`*

Comment: @jfs, нынче в моде длинные ответы, а время было уже позднее...

Comment: @avp, ну для точности формулировок их по-русски одним словом не назовёшь. Что-то типа *аргументы, которые не рассматриваются как опции*.

Comment: @0andriy, согласен. В этой области с формулировками на русском вообще беда. Вот, например, я пишу *опции*, но меня от этого слова передергивает (а иначе получаются какие-то многослойные конструкции).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это синтаксическая конструкция, описанная в стандарте [posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) для всех программ, следующих этому стандарту (а не только для конкретной программы *grep*):

> **Guideline 10**:
>       The first `--` argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the `'-'` character.

мой вольный перевод:

> первый аргумент `--`, не являющийся аргументом-опцией (т.е., насколько я понимаю, частью синтаксиса опции: `-опция аргумент-этой-опции`), должен быть воспринят как разделитель, обозначающий конец списка опций. любой последующий аргумент следует рассматривать как операнд, даже если он начинается с символа `'-'`.

---

в вашем примере `--` используется для того, чтобы программа *grep* не пыталась интерпретировать строку `'--with-debug'` как *опцию*, а считала её *аргументом*, т.е., в данном случае, регулярным выражением для поиска.

---

кстати: два аргумента `-e --with-debug` будут восприняты программой *grep* абсолютно точно так же, потому что опция `-e` [подразумевает наличие следующего аргумента — регулярного выражения](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html).